# Подскажите как убрать эту полосу

Tags: wordpress

Сайт на WP и она на всех страницах это пишет, как убрать это полосу с текстом?

[image: Полоса в заголовке]

Comment: Дайте ссылку на сайт, пожалуйста

Comment: http://seshdemidov.me/

Comment: Имеете доступ к файлу style.css ?

Comment: Да есть. там нужно исправить?

Answer (score 1):

В файле style.css найдите `.page_head, .author_div` и рядом с остальными атрибутами пропишите `display: none`;

Comment: Полоса с текстом осталась

Comment: Вы что то сделали не правильно. Я смотрю на код сайта и не вижу в том месте display: none;

Comment: Я добавил в строки .page_head в {display: none;} и только меню скрылось на мобильном

Comment: .page .page_head .postitle, .page .single_post .postitle, .archive .single_post .postitle {font-size: 24px!important;display: none;}
.page_head{ min-height:initial!important;display: none;}
.page_head .pagetitle_wrap{position:relative!important;display: none;}

Comment: http://www.seshdemidov.me/wp-content/themes/optimizer/style_core.css
В этом файле. Именно сюда - .page_head, .author_div